# How do I convert this loop into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I am trying to convert this loop with a nested if statement into list comprehension in python.  I think I am having trouble seeing the pattern in list comprehensions.  For context, the below loop scans through an array called ibi_a, and increases rowCount if each index it scans holds a value less than the variable antStart.

```
rowCount = 0
for row in range(0,len(ibi_a)):
    if ((float(ibi_a[row][timeStampCol])) < antStart):
        rowCount = rowCount+1 #increase rowCount to search for index of antStart
```

I have tried the following code with no luck.

```
rowCount = 0
rowCount = [rowCount+1 for row in range(0,len(ibi_a)) if ((float(ibi_a[row][timeStampCol])) < antStart]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions are for generating lists, which is not what your `for` loop is doing. You could do this if you want:

```
rowCount = sum((float(row[timeStampCol]) < antStart) for row in ibi_a)
```

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) acts as a count on boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't increase a count within the list comprehension; you'd just make a list of all the items that match your condition, and check the list's length:

```
rowCount = len([i for i in ibi_a if float(i[timeStampCol]) < antStart])
```

As an aside, unless you have some specific reason to create a `range` and a counter variable (`row`), it's a much better idea to loop over `i in ibi_a`, even in your original `for` loop. I would choose a more appropriate variable name for `i`, but I have no idea what "ibi_a" stands for or what its elements represent.

Comment: @Copperfield Oops. :)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Daniel, sometimes list comprehension can be abused in order to achieve better speed. The usual pretty vs faster, but of course to be sure is faster you need to time it.
I modeled a similar loop and bench-marked it both listcomp and loop and got pretty much same timing in this case. So I think you are better off keeping it as a loop.
Still and interesting exercise.

```
import random

l = [random.randrange(1, 100) for i in xrange(10000000)]
antStart = 30
def listcomp():
    rowCount = len([i for i in l if i < antStart])

def usingLoop():
    rowCount = 0
    for i in l:
        if i < antStart:
            rowCount = rowCount+1 

import timeit
print "list comp : ",timeit.timeit(listcomp, number=100)
print "loop : ",timeit.timeit(usingLoop, number=100)
```

Results were:

```
Item count : 10^6
list comp :  3.24901601876 s
loop :  3.13708115184 s

Item count : 10^7
list comp :  35.7664684531 s
loop :  31.1584190731 s
```

In this specific case you can see that with the bigger the list grows the overhead in the list allocation is over weighting the usual faster looping speed of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an appropriate use of list comprehensions. They are for - as the name implies - generating lists; what you want to do is to conditionally increment a variable. Stick with your for loop.